# Describing a set $C \subseteq A \times A$ with excluded elements under the constaint $(i,i) \not \in C$ if $i \in B$ for a fixed set $B \subseteq A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have two sets $A$ and $B$, where $B \subset A$ and I want to describe a new set $C$, which is consists of pairs $(i,j)$ under two conditions:

- $(i,j) \in C$ only if $ \space i,j \in A$
- $(i,i) \not \in C$ if $\space i \in B$.

My notation for this set is: $$C = \{(i,j)|i,j \in A, (i=j\in B)\}$$ I have used this notation because I don't know the correct notation and based on the comments / answer, this is wrong. Therefore, please go my above description for the properties of the set and not by this attempt to describe the set using set notation.

How do I formally describe the set $C$ in a way that is correct?

Comment: $C=(A\times A)\setminus\Delta_B,$ where $\Delta_B=\{(i,i)\mid i\in B\}.$ I used [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) $\times$, [set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) $\setminus$

Comment: The question is phrased unclearly. Your comment describes the question in the title, but the set described in the question $C = \{(i,j)|i,j \in A, (i=j\in B)\}$ is very different. This would imply that $C = (A \times A) \setminus \Delta _{\overline{B}}$ where $\Delta _{\overline{B}} =${$(i,i) | i \not \in B$} @AnneBauval

Comment: @RuianJian Indeed, your post was a little hard to understand and your notation was wrong. My previous comment corrected it, based on your words "excluded" and "except".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wrote an incorrect notation because I didn't know the correct one.

Comment: Yes, that is what I also understood. @FD_bfa I think this answers your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the notation that you are looking for is:

$$ C = (A \times A) \setminus \Delta_B \space \space \text{ where } \space \Delta_B = \{ (i,i) | i \in B \}$$

In plain English, this is the set containing all pairs of elements of $A$ excluding pairs of the same number which are also contained within the subset $B$.

In set notation, the correct way to write this is

$$ C = \{ (i,j) \in (A \times A) \space | \space  (i,i) \not \in B \}$$

---

One other thing worth mentioning is the notation that you use in the original question:

> "My notation is $\{(i,j)|i,j \in A, (i=j\in B)\}$"

This is **not** correct. The vertical line means "such that" and the comma means "and". Therefore, this notation means that this describes the set of all pairs $i,j \in A$ and if $i=j$, then it will only be in the set if $i \in B$ - which is almost the opposite of what you wanted.

You could adjust your notation slightly to describe $C$ in an equivalent way by replacing "$\in$" with $"\not \in$". This isn't the most precise way of describing the set (the characterization that I gave above is slightly more precise), but this would still be fine and means the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I want to change the exclusion conditions, i and j belong to A, but i and j cannot both belong to B. How should I describe it?

Comment: $D = \{ (i,j) \in (A \times A) \space | \space i \not \in B \lor j \not \in B \}$ The symbol $\lor$ is the mathematical symbol for the word "or". Does this answer your question? @RuianJian

Comment: I feel that my knowledge in this field is too scarce. Do you have any professional books that you recommend for me to read?

Comment: What level of mathematics are you working at? Most undergraduate mathematics book will usually treat this as assumed knowledge or have an introductory chapter explaining the set notation. My main advice would be to read, learn and try to familiarize yourself with the symbols I have used. Is there anything in particular that you aren't understanding? @RuianJian

Comment: Expanding upon my above comment. You should try to be familiar with the following concepts: $A \times B$ (cartesian product), $i \in A$ (elements), $j \not \in A$ (non elements), $A \land B$ (A and B), $A \lor B$ (A or B)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!